# How to post posts to pinterest automatically

Tags: pinterest

I have checked pinterest documentation, but I don't see how I can pin posts to board automatically. Furthermore, there is no option to pin posts via email.

So my question is: is it possible to pin posts to board automatically? Can I achieve this using PHP + Cronjob? How? If no, in what technologies I can achieve that result?

Code snippets are welcome.

Thank you!